# Force `Intellij IDEA 14` show chars inside strings instead of unicode codes

Tags: java, intellij-idea, character-encoding, intellij-14

The question is about how to force `Intellij IDEA 14` show national alphabet chars inside strings, which were encoded using native unicode codes:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "\u0422\u0438\u043f")
public class Тип {

    @XmlAttribute(name = "\u041a\u043e\u0434", required = true)
    protected String код;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "\u041d\u0430\u0438\u043c", required = true)
    protected String наим;

    ...

}
```

In other words I want to see `@XmlAttribute(name = "код", required = true)` instead of `@XmlAttribute(name = "\u041a\u043e\u0434", required = true)`.

Classes are generated automatically by `XJC` tool from a very unnatural XSD schema (all tags are in russian language).

The file is encoded in `UTF-8`, encoding settings of the project are:
[image]

Comment: It doesn't look like a problem of the IDE but a problem of the tag generation tool.

Comment: @DenysSéguret No, I don't agree. It is ok to use unicode codes. IDEA automatically  translate it into chars. Say if copy in buffer string `\u041a\u043e\u0434` and paste it anywere in class, IDEA will automatically show is as `код`.